# GitLab Rest API set GitLab Pages visibility to 'Everyone'

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-api, gitlab-pages

I have a program that allows me to automatically create a new GitLab project with the GitLab API and I would like to be able via this API to set the visibility of Pages to 'Everyone', which defaults to 'Only project members'. I looked in the [doc](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/api_resources.html) but I couldn't find anything about the Pages visibility setting. If anyone has an idea I would be interested in reading it.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

There's an attribute in the Create Project API to change the Pages visibility level. The attribute is called `pages_access_level` and the available options are `disabled`, `private`, `enabled`, or `public`. Using the option `public` should set the access level so Everyone can access your Page.

The `pages_access_level` attribute also exists when modifying a Project from the API.

Here's the docs for the [Create Project API](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/projects.html#create-project) where you can see the `pages_access_level` attribute.